# android - kotlin - how to save taken image in Room?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-room, uri

i'm using android studio, lenguage kotlin, to make my app where i want to deal with users and their cooking recipes. i need to use images of the dishes that the users want to share. i'm struggling with saving images .
now my code is:

```
                val context = LocalContext.current
                val file = context.createImageFile()
                val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(context),
                    context.packageName + ".provider", file
                )

                var capturedImageUri by remember {
                    mutableStateOf<Uri>(Uri.EMPTY)
                }

                val cameraLauncher =
                    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSuccess ->
                        if (isSuccess) {
                            capturedImageUri = uri
                        }
                    }

                val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
                ) {
                    if (it) {
                        cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        val permissionCheckResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            context,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                        )
                        if (permissionCheckResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
                        } else {
                            permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        }
                    },
                    contentPadding = ButtonDefaults.TextButtonContentPadding,
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.PhotoCamera,
                        contentDescription = "Camera icon",
                        modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize)
                    )
                    Spacer(Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
                    Text("Scatta foto")
                }

                if (capturedImageUri.path?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                            .data(capturedImageUri)
                            .crossfade(true)
                            .build(),
                        contentDescription = "image taken"
                    )

                    photoURI = saveImage(context.applicationContext.contentResolver, capturedImageUri)
                }
```

and i have also those functions:

```
fun saveImage(contentResolver: ContentResolver, capturedImageUri: Uri): String {
    val bitmap = getBitmap(capturedImageUri, contentResolver)

    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "IMG_${SystemClock.uptimeMillis()}")

    val imageUri =
        contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

    val outputStream = imageUri?.let { contentResolver.openOutputStream(it) }
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
    outputStream?.close()

    return imageUri.toString()
}

fun Context.createImageFile(): File {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
    return File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,
        ".jpg",
        externalCacheDir
    )
}

private fun getBitmap(selectedPhotoUri: Uri, contentResolver: ContentResolver): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28 -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
            contentResolver,
            selectedPhotoUri
        )
        else -> {
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
            ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
        }
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

the problem is that when i try to save images with `photoURI = saveImage(context.applicationContext.contentResolver, capturedImageUri)` the app stops ("MyApp has stopped"). Can someone help me?

Comment: When working with databases you can encode images as base64 and save the string, then you can retrieve the string and decode the Bitmap

Comment: Please remove all requesting for permission code. Its irrelevant for your problem and we gladly believe that you have CAMERA permission.

Comment: I wonder why you save image to media store. You said you wanted to store in room.

Comment: You got a jpg file from the camera app. You then convert that to bitmap. And then you compress the bitmap as jpg file to media store. This intermediate use of bitmap makes no sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)